# Need to call startupdatinglocation() while application is in background

Tags: ios, location, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm using `self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()` when my app is in background mode since 5 minutes or more but neither getting location update callback nor error. When it comes to foreground it works fine.
Another thing can we resume location service when it get pauses due to `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` variable.

I need to pause and resume both while application is in background but simple `startUpdatingLocation()` not works instead `stopUpdatingLocation()` works fine.

Comment: If you call `startUpdatingLocation` when your app is already in the background then you will receive location updates for a limited time *unless* you can enabled significant location updates when your app is in the foreground. You can also call `startUpdatingLocation` when your app is in the foreground to receive continuous updates.  How are you starting updates after 5 minutes in the background?  There is no way to schedule background activity in this way.

Comment: I'm using MotionActivityManager if user starts moving then i need to record moved location.